# Undefined variable "vision" or class "vision.CascadeObjectDetector"

Tags: matlab

Am trying to detect face object from an image using viola-jones algorithm. I used this instruction to detect the object `detect=vision.CascadeObjectDetector`. But am getting an error saying:

> Undefined variable "vision" or class "vision.CascadeObjectDetector".

I checked if "computer vision system toolbox" is installed or not (with the help of `ver` command), and yes it was installed. Though this package is installed am getting the above error. Any help?

Comment: which version of Matlab are you using? I can't reproduce your error with r2014a. It can be that this function is new.

Comment: my matlab version is " MATLAB Version 7.13.0.564 (R2011b)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Viola-Jones Cascade Object Detector, or the `vision.CascadeObjectDetector` method was released as of R2012a.  The reason why you're getting the method to be undefined is because you have an older version of MATLAB.  If you want to use the `vision.CascadeObjectDetector` method that's part of the Computer Vision toolbox, you'll need to upgrade to at least R2012a or newer.

Check the release notes for the Computer Vision toolbox here under R2012a: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/release-notes.html

Sorry if this isn't want you wanted to hear! Good luck!